# Can Panel4d and PanelND objects be saved?

Tags: python, pandas

I realise now that the experimental PanelND objects are going to fit my need brilliantly, except it appears I can't save them:

```
p4d = pd.Panel4D(np.random.randn(2, 2, 5, 4),
    labels=['Label1','Label2'],
    items=['Item1', 'Item2'],
    major_axis=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=5),
    minor_axis=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
p4d.save('p4d')
...
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'pandas.core.panelnd.Panel4D'>: attribute lookup pandas.core.panelnd.Panel4D failed
```

And if I try to write it to a HDFStore, I get:

```
TypeError: cannot properly create the storer for: [_STORER_MAP] [group->/p4d (Group) u'',value-><class 'pandas.core.panelnd.Panel4D'>,table->None,append->False,kwargs->{}]
```

Other than saving the individual DataFrames and stitching them together, how can I persist the higher dimensional obects?

Edit: I see that `store.append()` works for Panel4D but `save()` doesn't, and nor does `store.append()` for the example Panel5D.  I really am after higher than 4D, so the problem still persists.

Edit: more info:

I am trying to create an arbitrary dimensioned panel, within nested loops across the dimensions, and then to be able to slice that data, again arbitrarily, so I can process it (collate, plot, optimise)

In (rough) code:

```
for a in range(1,10):
    panel4ddict = {}
    for b in range(101, 150):
    paneldict = {}
        for c in range(500, 501):
            df = MakeDataFrame(a, b, c) # returns processed df
            paneldict[c] = df
        p3d = Panel(paneldict)
        panel4ddict[b] = p3d
    p4d = Panel4D(panel4ddict)
    panel5ddict[a] = p4d
panel5d = Panel5D(panel5ddict)

sliced = panel5d[:,3,5:6]
# and then do some plotting of my sliced DF
```

Comment: your can only save a Panel4D as a table (append works). put an example of what your are trying to do

Comment: HDFStorr not enabled for greater than 4dim directly, what do you want to store, more importantly how do you want to retrieve it? eg what kind of queries are you after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to store a Panel5D. Essentially you store each of the Panel4D as a separate group in the store, then reconstruct on read-back.

Note you might be better off storing this as DataFrame with multi-levels (3 or more) which in-effect contains the same information as a Panel5D, but unrolled long-wise.

```
 In [1]: from pandas.core import panelnd, panel4d
        from pandas.utils import testing as tm 

In [2]: Panel5D = panelnd.create_nd_panel_factory(
   ...:     klass_name='Panel5D',
   ...:     axis_orders=['cool', 'labels', 'items', 'major_axis',
   ...:                  'minor_axis'],
   ...:     axis_slices={'labels': 'labels', 'items': 'items',
   ...:                  'major_axis': 'major_axis',
   ...:                  'minor_axis': 'minor_axis'},
   ...:     slicer=panel4d.Panel4D,
   ...:     axis_aliases={'major': 'major_axis', 'minor': 'minor_axis'},
   ...:     stat_axis=2)

In [4]: p4d = panel4d.Panel4D(dict(L1=tm.makePanel(), L2=tm.makePanel()))

In [5]: p5d = Panel5D(dict(C1 = p4d, C2 = p4d+1))

In [6]: p5d
Out[6]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panelnd.Panel5D'>
Dimensions: 2 (cool) x 2 (labels) x 3 (items) x 30 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Cool axis: C1 to C2
Labels axis: L1 to L2
Items axis: ItemA to ItemC
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-03 00:00:00 to 2000-02-11 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: A to D

In [7]: store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5',mode='w')

In [9]: for x in p5d.cool:
    store.append(x,p5d[x])
   ...:     

In [10]: store
Out[10]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: test.h5
/C1            wide_table   (typ->appendable,nrows->360,ncols->2,indexers->[items,major_axis,minor_axis])
/C2            wide_table   (typ->appendable,nrows->360,ncols->2,indexers->[items,major_axis,minor_axis])

In [11]: store.close()
```

Comment: Thanks.  For this to work, x would be a string, right?  And the generic N-dim solution would need to build up a path of the dimensions.  My thoughts were to do this with a DataFrame.save() and have the filename reflect the combinations of dimensions.

Comment: x is a string. your storage scheme depends on what you are actually doing, eg the reason I built it this was to support appending operations. if u don't have a lot of data it really is probably easier to keep a multi index dataframe

Comment: Thanks.  I look forward to "native" persistence or pickling, but in the meantime, a variation on this will suit.